# Is it possible to wipe your phone remotely?

Tags: iphone

So my Iphone got snatched/stolen today and I would like to wipe all my things from my phone like apps and pictures and stuff. Is that possible to do from home? Thank you

Comment: Did you turn on Find My iPhone **before** it was stolen?  If so, then yes you can.  Follow [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201472).

Comment: Well yea, but the IPHONE was turned off when I went to check at home from my macbook

Comment: That would be good info to have in your question.  Please update it to add that info. See the link I provided from Apple, it has a section on what to do if the phone is offline.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you've registered your phone with Find my iPhone in iCloud. If you have, then log into icloud.com, select "Find iPhone",  pick your phone, click the i symbol and select "Erase iPhone". If you've not registered it then there's nothing you can do now, but be sure to register your next iPhone as soon as you buy it.

Comment: Yes and I did all that but it said the phone was turned off

Comment: then you'll have to wait until the next time it's turned on & can see a network.

Comment: To clarify, if you use Find My iPhone to place the phone into Lost Mode now, it [will take effect the next time the lost phone is powered on and connects to a network](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2700?locale=en_US). You don't have to wait around watching Find My iPhone until it next turns on.